# Show only a specific world region on map

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I want to show one part of the world on a map. For example, I want to show only the cities and states in India; how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is badly worded but this example may help.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2;
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = {latitude: 51.6657, longitude: 0.032563};

region.span=span;
region.center=location;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Comment: hey really sry that is y i told this as a example but thanks for ur answer